# Как сделать, чтобы GridPane растягивался на весь экран при разворачивании приложения на весь экран в Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

Уже в начале верстки приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой. При запуске приложения в SceneBuilder,  размер приложения имеет размер, который я указал Pref Width и Pref High у GridPane, это нормально, НО! когда я хочу растянуть приложение на весь экран(например двойным кликом) то GridPane вместе со своими компонентами остается в центре и не растягивается, а мне надо,чтобы компоненты в GridPane былм на весь экран, то есть растягивались
Что нужно поменять? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видео:
https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/lkgkrupw#

FXML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1300.0" styleClass="grid" stylesheets="@style.css" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="494.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="97.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="914.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="903.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="5.0" top="20.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <children>
            <JFXColorPicker prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="469.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" text="Label" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="5.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: обернуть ваш `GridPane` `AnchorPane`-ом

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!